# $f$ is continuous on the circle, and its Fourier series is absolutely convergent. Then its Fourier series converges uniformly to $f$.

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Corollary 2.3 in Fourier Analysis: An Introduction, Stein and Shakarchi, is not sufficiently detailed for me to fully understand.

I can see why the Fourier series uniformly converges to some continuous $g$
but how can I justify the equality between $\hat{g}(n)$ with $\hat{f}(n)$? (its Fourier coefficients).

I am not looking for hints, I tried to solve it myself following the "sketch" depicted in the book with no success.
Thank you in advance for any help.

the "sketch" depicted in the book.
"the Fourier coefficients of g are precisely $f_{n}$ since we can interchange the infinite sum with the integral(a consequence of the uniform convergence of the series)."

Update : currently stuck here
\begin{equation} \hat{g}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2 \pi} g(x)\cdot e^{-inx}dx \\
= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2 \pi} (\sum_{m \in Z} \hat{f}(m)\cdot e^{imx})\cdot e^{-inx} dx
\end{equation}

trying to get $\hat{g}(n) = \hat{f}(n)$

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE. Could you please elaborate on this question - write it as a question within the body, give an idea of the sketch and where you are stuck.

Comment: @user334732 revised, hope its better now, ty.

Comment: I don't understand fully but it looks like the answer given below says that the **uniform convergence** condition is sufficient for you to pull the summation sign out of the integral.

Comment: @user334732 the problem with the answer, is that as far as i know, if $f_n$ is given to be uniformly convergent, than it implies we can switch an expression of this form : $\int\limits_{x\in C}\sum\limits_{y\in D}f_n(x)dx= \sum\limits_{y\in D}\int\limits_{x\in C}f_n(x)dx$ . but this integral involves other expression which are not under the summation. which is a technical problem that I don't know how to tackle.

Comment: I edited your question. You were over-using 'n' and probably getting confused because of that.

Answer (score 4):

Uniform convergence is enough to justify interchange of an integral over a finite interval and an infinite sum. If $\sum \hat{f}(n)e^{inx}$ is absolutely convergent then $\sum |\hat{f}(n)|< \infty$ and so the Fourier series converges uniformly for $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$. Call the sum $h$. Then $h$ is continuous periodic function.  Now multiply by $e^{ikx}$, integrate from $o$ to $2\pi$ and take the integral inside the sum. You will get $\hat{h}(k)=\hat{f}(k)$.

Comment: What does $\hat{}$ signify here?

Comment: OP is talking about Fourier series of functions on the circle. In this context the hat is the standard notation used for Fourier coefficients.

Comment: Thank you, tried as you said. currently stuck here... \begin{equation} g_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2 \pi} g(x)\cdot e^{-inx}dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2 \pi} (\sum_{n \in Z} f_n\cdot e^{inx})\cdot e^{-inx}dx\end{equation} any help ? :)

Comment: @YarinMasas The first equality is the definition of $\hat g(n)$, which I gather Stein writes as $g_n$, The second equality is just the definition of $g$!

Comment: @YarinMasas Your using the same symbol $n$ with two meanings. Use another variable $m$ for the sum inside the integral. Next, pull the sum out of the integral and note that $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{imx}e^{-inx} dx=0$ if $n \neq m$. Rest should be easy.

Comment: Just curious, why can't we just conclude that $g=f$ by inspection of the sum: $$g=\lim_{N \to \infty} S_N(f)(\theta) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum^N_{n=-N} \hat{f} e^{in\theta}$$, where by definition, $$S_N(f)(x)=\sum^N_{n=-N} \hat{f} e^{2\pi inx/L}$$?